# Unix services on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, unix, nis, identity-management

Looking to remove a domain controller that is currently the NIS master for our identity management for unix service.  Need to know how to migrate the master to a different Windows server.

When you add a subordinate it always gets recognized as a unix server even if it is a Windows machine. How does one migrate the NIS master to a different Windows server?

Answer (score 1):

NIS data automatically replicates to all your domain controllers through AD replication.  To migrate to a new master, you should be able to simply install the unix services for windows NIS service on the new server (a DC), and then add it and promote it to master.